# scanf won't terminate with hex values?

Tags: c, hex, scanf

When I run this code:

```
main(){

    int hex;
    printf("Enter four hex values:\n");
    while(scanf("%x", &hex) == 1)
    {
        body
    }

}
```

It runs the body of the code, but then it shows the cursor and so the user can input more data until they enter NULL. How can I fix the while loop so once the user enters data, say 014C 456B 0894 0011 (some random hex numbers), it does the body and then the program terminates? I.e., why is the loop only ending when the user inputs NULL and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You call `scanf()` until you get an error or EOF (it is good that you test for the number of values — you get good marks for that).  If you only want to call it four times, then you have to limit it separately:

```
int main(void)
{
    int hex;
    printf("Enter four hex values: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 4 && scanf("%x", &hex) == 1; i++)
    {
        …body…
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note the use of `&hex` instead of just `hex` in the call to `scanf()`; you always need to pass a pointer (but if the object is an array, normally a string, then you pass it by name without an `&` in front).

If you need to detect whether you exited before getting four values, then define `i` outside the loop and test it afterwards.

Also note the explicit return type for `main()`; that is required by the current and previous versions of the C standard.  Only the archaic, quarter-century old first version of the standard allowed an implicit `int`.  And that standard required a return value from `main()` where the modern ones let you off the hook (more's the pity, IMO).

Comment: Yeah, I just rushed through the post when it comes to the &. Anyways, if I wanted to make this arbitrary now, as in they can enter in as many chunks of four hex digits as they want, how would I do this? I tried the what I found "standard" scanf while loop, but maybe it doesn't work the same with hex values?

Comment: Don't rush through the post. Take the time to make the code in the question as good as you can, avoiding as many gratuitous mistakes as possible, since the question is likely to survive for a long time, and you may not want silly mistakes to be visible in a day or two's time. It's also helpful to ask the whole question up front — it is fairer to the people who answer if they can see the whole problem. How are you going to stash the sets of 4 values before they're processed? One option is to wrap the loop I gave in a `while` loop; you just have to worry about how to terminate the outer loop.

Comment: I don't understand by "stash the sets of 4 values"... Currently the body of the program runs fine, it's just the program doesn't halt after the body executes... it just shows a cursor and the user can input more data, the body can do what it does with this new data, and the process keeps continuing until the user manually enters NULL. Then it terminates... So my question is how can I get the program to terminate after the first set of data instead of the user having to enter in NULL?

Comment: Is `NULL` the only data, or is it all non-hexadecimal and non-whitespace data that triggers the end of the loop? Perhaps [the `scanf` manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/scanf.html) might explain when and why your loop terminates...

Comment: When you say "enter four hex values", do you mean four separate multi-digit values, or do you mean an arbitrary number of 4-digit hex values?  I was assuming you meant the former; perhaps you mean the latter?  You can specify that `scanf()` process up to 4 hex digits at a time with `"%4x"` instead of just `"%x"`.  If the user types `A1B2C3 D4`, then that would be read as one group of 4 digits (`A1B2`) and two groups of two digits (`C3` and `D4`).  If you want to read 4 sets of hex digits, which is what I interpreted your question to mean, you use variations on the code I outlined in my answer.

Comment: As to what terminates the input: EOF terminates it, as does anything which is neither part of a hexadecimal number nor white space.  So, most punctuation would stop it (`+` and `-` at the front of a number wouldn't), and most alphabetic characters except `a-fA-F`, and `0x` or `0X` at the start of a number after an optional sign would be OK.